# Cisco ASA and missing logs to syslog server

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall, syslog

I would like to have some help with sending syslogs from a Cisco ASA 5555-X to a syslog server, graylog 3.2.1.
When running the following settings I could see a lot of information in the buffer with the command show logging.

```
logging enable
logging timestamp
logging emblem
logging buffer-size 52428800
logging buffered informational
logging trap informational
logging asdm debugging
logging device-id hostname
logging host INTERFACE 172.23.35.40 17/1514
logging permit-hostdown
```

But not in my syslog server. For example I'm not able to see the following:

```
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA-session-4-106023: Deny udp src UTB:172.22.44.54/51156 dst outside:216.58.207.226/443 by access-group "UTB_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA-session-4-106023: Deny udp src UTB:172.22.36.51/59611 dst outside:172.217.21.142/443 by access-group "UTB_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA-session-4-106023: Deny udp src UTB:172.22.44.54/60177 dst outside:172.217.21.130/443 by access-group "UTB_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA-session-4-106023: Deny udp src UTB:172.22.37.45/60442 dst outside:217.115.45.205/443 by access-group "UTB_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA-session-4-106023: Deny udp src UTB:172.22.41.83/61641 dst outside:216.58.207.200/443 by access-group "UTB_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA--4-434002: SFR requested to drop TCP packet from outside:23.21.154.58/443 to GUEST:X.X.X.X/37703
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:05 CEST: %ASA--4-434002: SFR requested to drop TCP packet from outside:23.21.154.58/443 to GUEST:X.X.X.X/37703
<164>:Mar 25 13:57:44 CEST: %ASA--4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 39 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 65 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 39313
```

I'm only able to see for example the following on my syslog server:

```
Mar 25 2020 13:57:44 ASA-INET : %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 39 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 65 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 39313
```

What about all the other 106023 and 434002 syslog messages? Is it not possible to send these syslog messages to a syslog server or is it something with my graylog server?

I have made a tcpdump between my firewall and the graylog server and it seems that all syslog messages are not hitting the firewall, how come? I'm using informational on both trap and buffered but yet they are different.

```
root@graylog01:/etc/elasticsearch# tcpdump -i ens32 port 1514 -v
tcpdump: listening on ens32, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:21:55.746278 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 23460, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 279)
    172.28.30.6.syslog > graylog01.1514: SYSLOG, length: 251
        Facility local4 (20), Severity warning (4)
        Msg: Mar 26 2020 13:21:55 ASA-INET : %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 39 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 78 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 47104\0x0a
12:22:05.377095 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 13258, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 189)
    172.28.30.6.syslog > graylog01.1514: SYSLOG, length: 161
        Facility local4 (20), Severity notice (5)
        Msg: Mar 26 2020 13:22:05 ASA-INET : %ASA-5-737003: IPAA: Session=0x0fd2c000, DHCP configured, no viable servers found for tunnel-group 'SSLVPN-Tunnelgroup'\0x0a
12:22:05.377164 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 1287, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 156)
    172.28.30.6.syslog > graylog01.1514: SYSLOG, length: 128
        Facility local4 (20), Severity info (6)
        Msg: Mar 26 2020 13:22:05 ASA-INET : %ASA-6-737026: IPAA: Session=0x0fd2c000, Client assigned 172.21.11.211 from local pool\0x0a
12:22:05.377168 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 16293, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 177)
    172.28.30.6.syslog > graylog01.1514: SYSLOG, length: 149
        Facility local4 (20), Severity info (6)
        Msg: Mar 26 2020 13:22:05 ASA-INET : %ASA-6-737006: IPAA: Session=0x0fd2c000, Local pool request succeeded for tunnel-group 'SSLVPN-Tunnelgroup'\0x0a
```

Comment: I'd bet it's just a server issue. Your logging level for trap is more than sufficient for those entries, so maybe your server is just filtering out or trying to categorize things incorrectly.

Comment: Hi @JesseP.
I have updated my post with a tcpdump which is evidence of that all syslog messages are not forwarded to my syslog server.

Comment: Can you provide the output from `show logging queue` to see if some messages are being discarded?

Comment: @JesseP.

`ASA-INET/pri/act# show logging queue 

        Logging Queue length limit : 512 msg(s)

        205615 msg(s) discarded due to queue overflow  

        0 msg(s) discarded due to memory allocation failure  

        Current 0 msg on queue, 512 msgs most on queue  `


It's been the same number for an hour, I think the errors are from some old stuff.

Comment: What's the 17/1514 after your logging host statement? That's normally where you defined a protocol and port but not in that format.

Comment: Thank you @JesseP. for looking into my problem.
When I execute the following command: `logging host INTERFACE 172.23.35.40 udp/1514` it is changed to `logging host INTERFACE 172.23.35.40 17/1514` so I think the number 17 stands for UDP somehow.
You have to write it in `protocol/port` in ASA CLI.

Comment: Interesting. Never noticed that before. I'll have to look into that further sometime.  It is possible that because those Deny and Drop events are implicit actions rather than a rule explicitly dropping them, that they're not being sent to syslog. The ASA does do that with denied traffic anyway.  It only forwards certain types of implicitly denied events.  For the rest, you actually have to have the "log" keyword on your rule or use Debug level logging.  So, you can test that by making a rule to match those denys or drops and have logging enabled on it/them to see if they get forwarded then.